# Making object follow the mouse issue

Tags: actionscript-3

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. So the problem is making a simple rectangle follow my mouse. I really don't understand why this code isn't working.
package Classes

```
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    import flash.events.Event;


    public class watever extends MovieClip
    {
        var stageRef:Stage;

        public function watever(x:Number, y:Number, stageRef:Stage)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.stageRef = stageRef;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveMe, false, 0, true);

        }


        public function moveMe(e:Event):void
        {
            this.x = mouseX;
            this.y = mouseY;

            trace(mouseX);
        }
    }
}
```

The object just goes on "strange" places, so I tried to trace mouseX and I got silly numbers in the output

```
-1373
1790
-1373
1790
-1373
1790
-1373
1790
-1373
1790
-1373
1790
-1373
```

However, if I declare it from the parent class it works fine. What's wrong with the code, please?
(Below is how it works from the parent class)

```
public function DocumentClass()
        {


            c = new watever(200, 200, stage)
            stage.addChild(c);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);

        }
        private function loop(e:Event):void
        {
            c.x = mouseX;
            c.y = mouseY;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse position is relative to the DisplayObject (`mouseX` is the same as `this.mouseX` if that makes it clearer), so if your `watever` MovieClip is at (0, 50) on the stage, and the mouse is at (0, 60), `watever.mouseY` will be 10.

When you read it from the document class, you're getting `mouseX` and `mouseY` relative to the stage, which is why it works correctly. You can just change moveMe() to do this:

```
public function moveMe(e:Event):void
{
    this.x = stageRef.mouseX;
    this.y = stageRef.mouseY;
}
```