# How do I stop my Hero movieclip from flickering when linked to it's respective class?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm an artist, not a programmer. Figured I'd throw that out there right away.

In my very basic game, which will eventually evolve into a side-scrolling shooter, I'm attempting to create a mouse event where the Hero (an airplane) character "sticks" to the mouse/mouse cursor. However, at runtime the Hero movieclip flickers and offsets by seemingly random positions. Yes, it follows the mouse, but it's extremely clunky. I'm sure the answer is simple, I hope!

I have a main FLA file that calls a function/class to start the game. The Hero object (linked to Hero class) is then added to the stage and moves with the mouse, or it's supposed to.

First code block (please forgive the cheesy name choices, those will change :) )...

CaptainSteelHawk.as -

```
package  {
    import flash.display.*;

    public class CaptainSteelHawk extends MovieClip {
        private var hero:Hero;

        public function startCaptainSteelHawk() {
            hero = new Hero();
            addChild(hero);

        }
    }

}
```

Second block, Hero.as -

```
package  {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Hero extends MovieClip {

        public function Hero() {

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,MoveHero);
        }
        public function MoveHero(e:Event) {
            this.x = mouseX;
            this.y = mouseY;
        }

    }

}
```

UDPATE! -  Found my answer here...FYI!  It was hard to explain my issue, since I can only speak so much code jargon.  But here's the fix...

[Making object follow the mouse issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348941/making-object-follow-the-mouse-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Hero has only 1 frame in it. Or has apprpriate `stop();` statements.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. I went back and checked the frame, there is only 1. I did add stop(); for good measure. But it's still having the same issue...?  Let me throw this out there, does it matter if Hero is a natively created Flash graphic? I imported a png file and made it a symbol. So my library has two items in it..the Hero MC and the png file from where it came from.

Comment: Hi again! FYI, I found my answer, see above.  But thanks again for your response!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent flickering, update your Hero class:

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class Hero extends MovieClip {

    public function Hero() {
       gotoAndStop(1);
       addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,MoveHero);
    }
    public function MoveHero(e:Event) {
        this.x = mouseX;
        this.y = mouseY;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas!  I added that to my Hero class, but the problem persists. I apologize, there's probably something I'm not explaining properly.  I may have to rethink this.

Comment: Hi again! FYI, I found my answer, see above.  But thanks again for your response!